# Triggering a search using external parameters on a subgrid in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a page that uses jqGrid with grids as subgrids.  I also have jQuery UI slider control on my page.  When the user changes the slider, I want to trigger a search on a field for the subgrid(s) which corresponds to the values behind the slider.

I've been looking at the documentation to try and find the best way to do this, but find [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_searching) documentation very confusing.  It also seems to be geared towards making another call to the server, which I don't want to do since I'm using `loadonce: true`.

I've been able to acheive a work-around by iterating over the subgrid rows and calling `hide()` on the rows that don't meet the criteria, but this does not hold up to pagination.  What would be the best way to perform this type of externally triggered search on a subgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by reverse engineering the triggerToolbar method in the jqGrid source file (the pattern `'[id^=grid_GR][id$=_t]'` matches my subgrid IDs):

```
function external_subgrid_search() {
    var ruleGroup = '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Inv","op":"bw","data":"25"}]}';
    $('[id^=grid_GR][id$=_t]').each(function () {
        var p = $(this).getGridParam('postData');
        p.filters = ruleGroup;
        $(this).setGridParam({ postData: p, search: true }).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1}]);            
    });
}
```

This will do the same thing as if I had entered '25' into the search toolbar for the field 'Inv'.  Keep in mind that this is *VERY* stripped down.  It ignores any beforeSearch or afterSearch functions you may have defined and assumes you have local data.  But, hopefully it can act as a starting point for anyone else trying to do something similar.